# Android Jelly Bean TTS Speech Rate

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I've been working with the beautiful new Android TTS "Jelly Bean voice," but I'm having trouble setting the speech rate.

For example, given the following example code: http://code.google.com/p/simple-jellybean-tts-example/

When I use the old-style TTS voice (namely, KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS is set to false in tts.speak(...)), tts.setSpeechRate works as it should, but when using the new-style, "Jelly Bean voice" (namely, KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS is set to true), setSpeechRate seems to have no effect on the spoken text.

Is there some workaround for this? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.